# Rosbag delay and time jump

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rosbag

I ran a node that publishes images (with image_transport), laser_scan messages and a simple custom message. I recorded these 3 topics with rosbag.

During the time it was running I didn't noticed any delay or time jump in my messages. But when I play back my data with rosbag I have big time jumps and I loose a lot of data.
It's not even in a buffer, it just seems the data was not recorded. If I pause my rosbag and play it message by message I can see that certain messages are missing.

Do you know why it happens ? I know that images can be pretty demanding for ros2, can it comes from that ? (I'm working with Humble).

Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

When you're logging if you overrun any of your physical limitations data will be dropped if it can't be transferred.

Make sure that you're not saturating your network bandwidth getting to the logger, nor are you trying to write data faster than your storage medium can support. You don't mention your storage media, but write speeds can vary significantly between similar models or choices of technology.